# Trying to match a sequence if not preceded by one group, but yes if preceded by another

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, oniguruma

This is getting a little meta, but I'm trying to figure out a regex to match regexes for syntax highlighting purposes. There's a nice long backstory, but in the interest of brevity I'll skip it. Here's what I'm trying to do: I need to match a comment (preceded by `#` and terminated at the end of the line) only if it is **not** inside a character class (`[...]`), although it should be matched if there is a complete (closed) character class earlier in the line.

The complicating factor is escaped square brackets — while a plain `[` earlier in the line not followed by a closing `]` would indicate that we're still in a character class, and therefore illegal, an escaped bracket `\[` could be present, with or without the presence of a closing escaped bracket `\]`.

Maybe some examples will help. Here are some instances where a comment **should be** matched:

- `(\h{8}-\h{4}-\h{4}-\h{4}-\h{12}) # match UUID` (no square brackets at all)
- `([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*) # valid Python identifier` (paired unescaped square brackets)
- `(\||\[|\?) # match some stuff` (escaped opening square bracket)

Here is an example of where an "attempted comment" **should not** be matched:

```
[A-Za-z # letters
 0-9_-.] # numbers and other characters
```

(the first line should not be matched, the second one is fine)

I'm by no means a regex master (which is why I'm asking this question!), but I have tried fiddling around with positive and negative lookbehinds, and trying to nest them, but I've had zero luck except with

```
(?<!\[)((#+).*$)
```

which matches a comment only if not preceded by an opening square bracket. Once I started nesting the lookarounds, though, and trying to match if the opener was preceded by an escape, I got stumped. Any help would be ... helpful.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes. I'm working on the [`AAAPackageDev`](https://github.com/SublimeText/AAAPackageDev) plugin for Sublime, on a syntax highlighting definition for highlighting regexes.

Comment: check my answer. If not, i wnat little more clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rather simple, but in works with cases from your example. So try this:

```
(?<=[\][)]\s)(#(.*))$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iR0oA2/8)

it match comment only if preceded by closing bracket and space.

### **EDIT**

As I thought you case is much more complicated, so maybe try this one:

```
^(?=(?:[-\w\d?*.+|{}\\\/\s<>\]]|(?:\\[\[\]()]))+(#+.*)$)|^(?=^[\[(].+?[\])]\s*(#+.*)$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yW7bX2/1)

It will match only by groups (it is not matching any text at all, as it use only positive lookahead, but grouping is lookarounds is allowed). Or if you want to match directly, match more text, and then get what you want with groups with something like:

```
^(?:(?:[-\w\d?*.+|{}\\\/\s<>\]])|(?:\\[\[\]()])|^[\[(].+?[\])])+\s*(#+.*)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yW7bX2/2)

However in both cases, you probably would need to add more characters occuring in regular expressions to first alternative `(?:[-\w\d?*.+|{}\\\/\s<>\]])`. For example, if you want it to match also comment in `(\[ # works if escaped [ is in group` you need to add `(` to alternative. But I am not sure is it what you wanted.

### EDIT "invalid scope"

Try with:

```
^(?:(?:[-\w\d?*.+|{}\\\/\s<>\]\(])|(?:\\[\[\]()])|^[\[(].+?[\])])+\s*(?<valid>(?:#+).*)$|^[-\[\w\d?*.+|{}\\\/\s<>\(]+(?<invalid>(?:#+).*)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yW7bX2/4)

Comment: It looks promising, but check out https://regex101.com/r/iR0oA2/5 - it works fine if `\[` is in parens, but not if it's on its own.

Comment: Never mind - check out https://regex101.com/r/iR0oA2/6 - I just added `\[` to the lookbehind and it works. Feel free to update your answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @MattDMo I updated answer, but still I have a question, I thought that you don't want to match comments after opening bracket, and now you want it to match, what changed? My regex will match comment after closing bracket, or escaped opening bracket (not other character), it this what you wanted?

Comment: Never mind, I see what you did now. I'll modify it some more to add support for more `#` characters and more spaces between the end of the regex and the beginning of the comment, but what you have here is great. Thanks!

Comment: Just found another problem - https://regex101.com/r/iR0oA2/10. The two bottom use cases aren't working...

Comment: @MattDMo I updated answer, take a look, maybe you will find it useful

Comment: Fantastic! I [updated](https://regex101.com/r/yW7bX2/3) the second one, adding `\(` to the first alternative, and making `#+` its own capture group, and all my test cases are working so far. I'd upvote this again, but I can't :)

Comment: Oh, one more request (if it's possible) - for `[A-Za-z # letters`, would it be possible to capture that comment as well? I'd like to assign an `invalid` scope to it. Thanks!

Comment: @MattDMo I am not sure, is it what you expect, but check my update

Comment: Thanks again! This is definitely getting me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Think you mean this,

```
^\[[^\]]*\].*#.*$|#(.*)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eP2gY9/2)

OR

```
^\[[^\]]*\].*#.*$(*SKIP)(*F)|#.*$
```

Comment: The first one almost does it, except for `[A-Za-z0-9_] # letters and numbers` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eP2gY9/4)

Comment: where it matches perfectly. ie, `[anychar] #.*` won't match. So that `[A-Za-z0-9_] # letters and numbers` won't get captured.

Comment: not to capture only if it contains a `\n` at the middle? https://regex101.com/r/eP2gY9/5